# Devise logout fails if there is no `javascript_include_tag :all`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Session destroy by using Devise fails.
But if I rewrite `<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>` to `<%= javascript_include_tag :all %>`.

But latter way is now deprecated as far as I know.
I disabled turbolinks, and my config are like these.

config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

and logout link.

```
<%= link_to "log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

and error message is `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/users/logout"):`

I thought `<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>` is same with `<%= javascript_include_tag :all %>` if I write application.js correctly.

I have no idea why this happens, and how to solve this problem?
I don't want to use deprecated `:all` method.

Comment: to simulate a `delete` request, rails needs some javascript. So if you remove all javascript, no more links with delete

Comment: If `<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>` exists in the code, all javascript are loaded, aren't they?

Comment: everything you declare in application.js

Comment: That means I should require some javascript for devise in application.js? I couldn't find any info about that. Do you know what should I add to `application.js`?

Comment: No. It's basic rails js, included in the jquery gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Rails didn't find the route. You can check in devise.rb if the configuration is

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

I think default is ":delete" if the devise version is not very old. But it could be ":get", if it is ":get", either you change the config to

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

or change the log out link to

```
<%= link_to "log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :get %>
```

Or no matter what, all use ":get" to take a shot.

Comment: Thanks with `:get` works fine. I couldn't find the reason why `:delete` doesn't works, though.

Comment: I think I use ":delete" once and it could work, but i forget what is the extra work to do, maybe config routes? I remember use ":delete" some problems will happen, and ":get" always works fine, so finally I used ":get".